# FreeTDS - Return UTF-8 Character Set Data

Tags: php, pdo, iconv, freetds

I'm using a MS SQL Server 2008 with PHP PDO: I have a PHP PDO class that is taking a Windows Character Set and converting data to UTF-8 manually. Something like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM something_somewhere);
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
foreach ($result as $row) {
foreach (get_object_vars($row) as $key => $value) {
    $row->$key = (mb_detect_encoding($value, mb_detect_order(), true) === 'UTF-8') 
            ? $value : iconv('iso-8859-1', 'utf-8', $value);
}
$results[] = $row;
```

}

iconv() works great, but writing this all of the time is tedious. Is there anyway to configure FreeTDS to convert to UTF-8?

I was reading about the FreeTDS configuration for Moodle at:

https://docs.moodle.org/22/en/FreeTDS

My current /etc/freetds.conf file (not editable, so I'll have to get the admin to change it):

```
#   $Id: freetds.conf,v 1.12 2007/12/25 06:02:36 *** Exp $
#
# This file is installed by FreeTDS if no file by the same
# name is found in the installation directory.
#
# For information about the layout of this file and its settings,
# see the freetds.conf manpage "man freetds.conf".

# Global settings are overridden by those in a database
# server specific section
[global]
        # TDS protocol version
;       tds version = 4.2

        # Whether to write a TDSDUMP file for diagnostic purposes
        # (setting this to /tmp is insecure on a multi-user system)
;       dump file = /tmp/freetds.log
;       debug flags = 0xffff

        # Command and connection timeouts
;       timeout = 10
;       connect timeout = 10

        # If you get out-of-memory errors, it may mean that your client
        # is trying to allocate a huge buffer for a TEXT field.
        # Try setting 'text size' to a more reasonable limit
        text size = 64512

# A typical Sybase server
[egServer50]
        host = symachine.domain.com
        port = 5000
        tds version = 5.0

# A typical Microsoft server
[egServer70]
        host = ntmachine.domain.com
        port = 1433
        tds version = 7.0
```

I assume I need to edit the [global] settings, adding both:

tds version = 7.0

client charset = UTF-8

Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you need to set UTF in freetds configuration file.

1. Open `freetds.conf`.
2. add `client charset = UTF-8` in your connection settings.

Comment: I was reading about FreeTDS with Moodle (Moodle Dosc: https://docs.moodle.org/22/en/FreeTDS ) and noticed a version 7.0+ requirement. It looks like I might need to upgrade?